# Filipino Citizen transiting through Istanbul

Tags: visas, transit-visas, turkey, filipino-citizens

Hello I have a friend who is traveling form Manila to the Dominican Republic making a change of planes in Istanbul and Madrid. Does he need to get a visa to transit through Istanbul?